# Как убрать нажатую кнопку aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Столкнулся с проблемой удаления кнопок я хотел удалить кнопку зарегистрироваться после его использование но не знаю как это реализовать было бы хорошо если кто нибудь напишет код

```
@dp.message_handler(commands="start")
async def start_command(message: types.Message):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    keyboard.add(KeyboardButton(text="Зарегестрироваться", request_contact=True))
    keyboard.add(KeyboardButton(text="Запросить погоду", request_location=True))
    await message.answer("Привет напиши мне название города, я пришлю тебе сводку к погоду!", reply_markup=keyboard)
    menu = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(InlineKeyboardButton('Первая кнопка',
       callback_data='button_one')).add(InlineKeyboardButton('Вторая кнопка', 
       callback_data='button_two'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так

```
@dp.message_handler(commands="start")
async def start_command(message: types.Message):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    keyboard.add(KeyboardButton(text="Зарегистрироваться", request_contact=True))
    keyboard.add(KeyboardButton(text="Запросить погоду", request_location=True))
    await message.answer("Привет напиши мне название города, я пришлю тебе сводку к погоду!", reply_markup=keyboard)


@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentTypes.CONTACT)
async def get_contact(msg: types.Message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True).add(
        KeyboardButton(text="Запросить погоду", request_location=True))
    await msg.answer("asdasd", reply_markup=markup)
```

Comment: Спасибо сейчас попробую